# BMXAA1470E - A transaction cannot be committed to the Java Message Service (JMS) queue

Tags: java, jms, maximo

We have recently started seeing BMXAA1470E - A transaction could not be committed to the Java Message Service queue errors in our Maximo setup. We have two outbound jms servers,  sqoutuiserver and sqoutint server which are hosted on of the UI and INT managed servers on a clustered environment. When I look at the logs, there are no errors and the memory on these servers seems to be ok as well. However any operation that triggers a message to the oubound queue will throw the BMXAA1470E  error and we usually restart the Ui and INT servers to resolve the issue.

Can someone please let me know if you had such an issue in the past and share some direction to understand the root cause of the issue?

Environment set up:

IBM Maximo Asset Management 7.5.0.6

DB - Oracle -11.2

App Server- Weblogic Application Server 10.3.6.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this issue before. On our case, it meant there was some corruption (or fill-up) of the tables on the JMS schema. The only way I've found to fix it is to recreate the messaging engine message store schema (Buses > (your bus name) > Messaging engines > (messaging engine name) > Data store > Schema Name), change Schema Name, stop all application servers, nodeagents and the deployment manager, and then restart these. The message store tables will be recreated.

As an alternative, this article states that you can just truncate them. I haven't tried that, though.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tjm0399_.html